# USB Printing using chrome browser on Mac

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am testing chrome.usb and chrome.printerProvider api.
I am able to connect my usb printer using chrome.usb deviceinfo (sample app ) and get my device info. I am not able to actually print using the chrome.usb usb-label-printer app. This app seems to print using a label printer but it did not work when I use  my USB printer. I have the vendorId, productId, endpoint correctly configured. How do I actually print?

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: How do I actually print?